# Quitar autocompletar contraseñas de navegadores

Tags: genexus

en una pantalla tengo un acceso con un código, y el campo de ingreso, me sugiere las contraseñas guardadas del navegador. Hay manera de forzar mediante la aplicacion que esto no pase? Saludos

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En las propiedades de la variable o atributo fijate "Input History"

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?21731,InputHistory%20property

Saludos!

Comment: No me sirve porque es un campo de entrada de tipo password  


"Considerations
This property doesn't work for Date based fields.

When the IsPassword property is set to yes the Input History property is disabled.

A value is "saved" for the input history when an action is executed on the screen the field is on."

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).